# Deploy/publish database only in TFS build

Tags: database, tfs, build

We are doing nightly builds of a project. It builds, runs code analysis, recreates as database from versioned schema, runs unit tests and publishes to an IIS site. All good.

We've got a different build profile for rolling build. We want to do exactly the same apart from the "publish to web" bit. Is this possible? Just build, recreate database and run tests. We are using the following MSBuild arguments

/p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=InProc /p:MSDeployServiceUrl=localhost /p:DeployIisAppPath="/MySite"

for the nightly build. I can't find any information on how to just do publish SQL.

Thanks,
- Mansos